# Optimizing MasterMind Code and string operations in python

Tags: python, string, optimization

I am writing a solver for MasterMind in which I must take in a guess and an answer and return some representation of the number of black and white pegs where a black peg represents a correct color in the correct spot and a white peg represents a correct color in the incorrect spot. I have to run this code for about 2 million iterations and so it needs to be as fast as possible. Currently the biggest time sinks of this are the split and index calls, but I'm not sure how to remove them. Any ideas on how to make this code run faster while maintaining its functionality?

```
def returnPegs(guess, answer):
        guessList = guess.split(" ")
        answerList = answer.split(" ")
        response = ""
        iterator = [0,1,2,3]
        for i in iterator:
            if answerList[i] == guessList[i]:
                response = response + "B"
                guessList[i] = "alsoNotAColor"
                answerList[i] = "notAColor"
        for j in iterator:
            if guessList[j] in answerList:
                response = response + "W"
                answerList[answerList.index(guessList[j])] = "notAColor"
                guessList[j] = "alsoNotAColor"
        return response
```

To ensure clarity. My input is a string of four colors separated by spaces, and my output doesn't have to have any particular form so long as it is unique for every combination of black and white pegs.

After some heavy optimization This is the current state of the code:

```
 def returnPegs(guess, answer):
    pegs = 0 
    for answerPeg, guessPeg in zip(answer, guess):
        if answerPeg == guessPeg:
            pegs += 5
        elif guessPeg in answer:
            pegs +=1
    return pegs
```

Optimizing further, kinda going back to some original code, this version is actually the fastest of them all. By about a factor of 4 over the first and a factor of 2 over the second.

```
def returnPegs(guess, answer):
    response = 0
    iterator = [0,1,2,3]
    for i in iterator:
        if guess[i] == answer[i]:
            response += 5
            guess[i] = "alsoNotAColor"
            answer[i] = "notAColor"
        elif guess[i] in answer:
            response += 1
            answer[answer.index(guess[i])] = "notAColor"
            guess[i] = "alsoNotAColor"
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, this code should do what you need:

```
def returnPegs(guess, answer):
    guesses = guess.split()
    answers = answer.split()

    pegs = []

    for answer, guess in zip(answers, guesses):
        if answer == guess:
            pegs.append('B')
        elif guess in answers:
            pegs.append('W')

    return ''.join(pegs)
```

`zip()` zips together two sequences:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> zip(a, b)
[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]
```

Comment: I really like this answer, but it actually runs a little bit slower on my machine. Ran a little bit faster once I got rid of the join, but the split is still the big time sink. Would regex be faster?

Comment: Why are you using strings in the first place? Split up `guess` and `answer` before passing them in.

Comment: Sadly its making a call to a function that isn't mine, but if that's the only way then I may just rewrite it.

Comment: `.split()` and `.join()` shouldn't be used at all for this sort of stuff. They just take up time without being useful.

Comment: Alright, so rewrote input, and got rid of join, and then also changed pegs to just be an integer where black is a 5 and white is a 1, so any number is still a unique combination. Not sure if it's quite fast enough, but might have to do. Will repost current code.

Comment: ah wait, this code changes the actual result. For instance, if input was [Green, Blue, Red, Blue], [Blue, Yellow, White, Black] This method would return two Whites instead of just one like it should.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: You sure? I get `returnPegs('GBRB', 'BYWB') == 'WB'`.

Comment: Black != Blue I think is the issue here.

Comment: Got a version that runs significantly faster and doesn't have this problem. Posted the code, but thanks for helping me think through this, couldn't have done it without you!